# HTML Cannot remove whole page "inside" border (body border?)

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website and I suddenly noticed that in IE9 nearly only layout of mine has such issue (different from other websites that I recently browsed)

There is a gray border around my page which I cannot remove.

I already have `body{margin:0;padding:0;}` and I tried `html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}` but it still continued to exist.

Here is a small screenshot [image]

Help me remove this border please.

Comment: It only appears if I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` but I want to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those borders are from Internet Explorer itself, you can't remove them.

Comment: but other websites do not have such border in IE.

Answer (score 1):

To remove that spaces just add this to your css:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```